# Intel WIFI stop working after update 14.04 LTS Dell Inspiron 5558

Tags: drivers, dell, iwlwifi

After common update wifi device stopped to work.
When I type wifi in terminal I get:

```
wifi      = none (no device)
```

Then I tried following to get info from lspci:

```
lspci -vnn | grep 'Network'
```

and get

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
```

After that I have tried to find solution on internet suitable for my case, during that time I learned that I should look after driver package under name **iwl**.
The following is what I have tried without success:

```
modinfo iwlwifi
```

result with log until firmware

```
    filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko
    version:        backported from Linux (v3.16.2-0-g62de88e) using backports v3.16.2-1-0-g9d017dd
    license:        GPL
    author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
    version:        in-tree:
    description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
.
.
.
    depends:        compat,cfg80211
    vermagic:       3.13.0-165-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline
```

then I tried

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Package not installed

modinfo iwlvmv
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-165-generic/updates/dkms/iwlmvm.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v3.16.2-0-g62de88e) using backports v3.16.2-1-0-g9d017dd
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     81F5072D244C5BDF8B697D0
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-165-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline
```

Figured out dependencies and for each of them I get **modinfo** and the same result for **sudo modprobe** - modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'XXXX': Package not installed

I did also

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

I get this

```
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
```

I really do not know what to do next.

Comment: Did this Dell come with Ubuntu pre-installed? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes it did. Manufacture Date: 03/10/2015

Comment: I suspect that the dkms version of iwlwifi is faulty. You could certainly ask Dell about it as they pre-installed that version. However, as 14.04 is going to be end-of-life on April 30, 2019, I suggest that you try Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in a live session, confirm that the wireless works as expected and, if so, install it.

Answer (score 0):

"Package not installed" from modprobe hints at a problem with module signing (Ubuntu kernels ship with module signature checks).

I don't know exactly what broke with the last update, but I've fixed this problem by downgrading the "dkms" package (from 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.10 to 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5). This also pulled in downgrades for grub and shim packages.

I suspect dkms 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9 would also work, but I couldn't find a .deb for that version on Ubuntu mirrors.

After downgrading dkms it was also necessary to rebuild iwlwifi modules:

```
rm -r /var/lib/dkms/iwlwifi-3.16.2
dkms build iwlwifi-3.16.2/1.0
dkms install iwlwifi-3.16.2/1.0
```

After that iwlwifi module started working for me again.